# AngularJS Service Singleton Usage?

Tags: angularjs

I need a service that will remain instantiated during the life of the application and offer basic properties, similar to C# syntax.  For example, if I create a `profile` service, I would like to get and set the `User` from within my controller with the following syntax;

```
activate();

function activate() {
    vm.user = profile.user;
}

function login (user, pass) {
    api.login(user, pass)
        .then(function(response){
            profile.user = response.data;
            vm.user = profile.
        });
}
```

Is the following example correct for this?..

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('blocks.auth')
        .service('profile', profileService);

    profileService.$inject = [];
    function profileService () {

        this._user;

        this.user = {
            get function () {
                return this._user;
            },
            set function (value) {
                this._user = value;
            }
        };

    }

})();
```

Sorry for the newbie question, but the syntax on the service looks incredibly odd and confusing.

Comment: Are you certain that you can wire up the getter and setter functions that way? I've never seen that syntax in Angular (that's not to say it can't be done).

Comment: Is there a cleaner or more logical syntax?

Comment: That syntax looks very clean, I'm just surprised it works. I didn't know that you could assign get/set to an object in a service like that and it would wire it all up for you automatically. Is this TypeScript?

Comment: @Lex : No, this is Newbie#.  I cobbled it together after doing searches.  Really HATE the `this` keyword being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having also come from C# / .NET, I think I know what's messing with your head.  Your brain is probably still thinking about the scope and variable definitions that you're used to seeing.

Here's how I would structure your service:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('blocks.auth')
        .factory('profile', profileService);

    function profileService () {

        var _user = {};

        var service = {

            // User (read / write)
            get user () {
                _user = _user || {};
                return _user;
            },
            set user (value) {
                if (value && !value.id) { return; }
                _user = value || {};
            },

            // isUserLoaded (read only ... no setter)
            get isUserLoaded () {
                return (_user && _user.id != null);
            },

            // Clear (similar to class method)
            clear : function () {
                _user = {};
            }

        };

        return service;
    }

})();
```

Think of the `service` object as your `class` in C#.  This still uses your underscore for the local variable so you can see it a bit better.  Heck, you could also move the `_user` variable into the `service` object if you want to mimic the C# class a bit closer.  Then, the `get`ters and `set`ters are almost identical.

The only oddity is the `clear()` function I've added... mainly because of the syntax.

Comment: Oh, man!  Thank you so much!  Your explanation is exactly what I needed.  It definitely bridges the C#-to-JavaScript gap for me.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, angular service is singleton. Just make sure you inject the service into your controller.

Something like below (untested):

```js
angular.module('blocks.auth').controller('myController', function ($scope, api) {  
  
  $scope.activate() {
    vm.user = profile.user;
  }

  $scope.login (user, pass) {
    api.login(user, pass)
        .then(function(response){
            profile.user = response.data;
            vm.user = profile.
        });
  }
  
  $scope.activate();
  
})
```